# Debugging file associations of Electron app in MacOS

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

Our Electron app uses electron-builder and adds file associations to MacOS when it is installed from a .dmg file. Setting the association works fine, but we don't seem to handle the 'open-file' correctly inside the app, as files don't load as expected.

Is there a way of working with file association and debugging the app at the same time? I know that I could change the code and add some console logs, build the .dmg file, install it, try it and repeat. But this workflow seems very tedious, so I'm looking for a simpler way of doing this.

Can I somehow manually register the file association for the dev version of the Electron app, so that it's enough to build it and then click on some files in Finder? Or can I trigger the 'open-file' event of my app manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it‘s enough to simply build the complete app package. If macOS finds an .app file somewhere on the disk, it is available in Finder‘s file associations.